# How can I rename factors based on the column names of another data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse, factors

I have a column in a dataframe holding subjects:

```
sub <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F")
subjects <- data.frame(sub)
```

I have another data frame containing columns of subjects (where subjects are only found in one column):

```
one <- c("A", "C", "F")
two <- c("B", "D", NA)
three <- c("E", NA, NA)
newsubjects <- data.frame(one, two, three)
```

I'm wanting to rename the subjects in the first dataframe to the column name found in the second dataframe corresponding to that subject.

So for example, I want the A, C, and F subjects in the first dataframe to be renamed 'one'. Doing this manually would take a long time so I'm hoping theres a way to use the columns in the second data frame to do this.

I've tried a bunch of stuff with forcats::fct_recode and levels but nothing works because I'm not using these functions correctly. Eg IIRC one of my attempts looked something like this:

```
subjects %>%
      mutate(new_var = forcats::fct_recode(sub,
            !!! setNames(as.character(subjects$sub), newsubjects$one)))
```

Which I know is completely wrong. Part of the problem is it's difficult fo me to articulate my problem in a way that returns relevant search results. Thank you for any help you can provide, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `purrr::map()`, derive a list pairing column names with values from `newsubjects`. Then unpack this inside `forcats::fct_collapse()` to recode values in `subjects`.

```
library(purrr)
library(forcats)

new_ids <- map(newsubjects, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)])

subjects$sub <- fct_collapse(subjects$sub, !!!new_ids)

subjects
```

```
     sub
1    one
2    one
3    two
4    one
5    one
6    one
7    two
8  three
9    one
10   one
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reshape `newsubjects` longer, you could join the two tables:

```
library(tidyverse)
subjects %>%
  left_join(newsubjects %>% 
            pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "new_sub", values_to = "sub")) 

Joining, by = "sub"
   sub new_sub
1    A     one
2    A     one
3    B     two
4    C     one
5    C     one
6    C     one
7    D     two
8    E   three
9    F     one
10   F     one
```

Comment: This works with my reprex but not when I try to apply it to my actual data. The 'new_sub' column is just filled with NAs. My actual 'sub' column is 14,000 rows (containing a mix of subjects and NAs), while the columns in 'newsubjects' dataframe are between 14 and 76 rows (and the shorter ones are padded out with NAs). Is there anything obvious you can see that I need to change when translating to my actual data?

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of equal length in one, two, three you could also create a lookup

```
library(dplyr)

sub <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F")
subjects <- data.frame(sub)

one <- c("A", "C", "F")
two <- c("B", "D", NA)
three <- c("E", NA, NA)

additions <- c(one, two, three)

lookup <- data.frame(
  sub = additions %>% unlist(), 
  value = rep(1:length(additions), each=length(additions[[1]])))

subjects %>% inner_join(lookup) %>% select(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
gsub("\\d", "", names(unlist(newsubjects))[match(subjects$sub, unlist(newsubjects))])
```